# Bootstrap row stays at 1px when inserting d3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg

I have been trying to make a responsive dashboard using D3. I have some previous experience but haven't used bootstrap extensively before. Posts I have researched mentioned using bootstrap and then ViewBox to make D3 SVG's reactive.

However, when I tried this I found my SVG's didn't show up. Specifically the bootstrap row  remains at 1px of height even after I have entered the SVG. Even more weird is that if I hard-code an SVG with height = 960 width = 500 (i.e. hard-coded in html) then the row still remains at 1px.

I've looked everywhere but I can't find what is wrong. Any help with this would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>


  <script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainindex.css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This is some text.</p> 

  <div class ="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" id = "barchartdiv"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id = "leftovers"> Some stuff here </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Another chart here </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
<script>



d3.json("data/pdoconnection.php", function(error, data) {

    dataset = data; 
    console.log(dataset);
    console.log("data retrieved")


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60},
    dynwidth = 960,
    aspect = 500/960,
    width = dynwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = dynwidth*aspect - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#barchartdiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  x.domain(dataset.map(function (d) { return d.sortorder; }));

  y.domain([d3.min(dataset.map(function (d) { return d.ipcount; })), d3.max(dataset.map(function (d) { return d.ipcount; }))]);


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of Hits (IPs)");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.ipcount < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.sortorder)+10; })
      .attr("width", (x.rangeBand() - 20))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(Math.max(0, d.ipcount)); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(y(0) - y(d.ipcount)) ; })
      .attr("rx", 15)
      .attr("ry", 15);

});


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try setting the dimensions of the svg with firebug (or the like) and see if it gets bigger. ```<svg style="width:960px;height:500px">..```

Comment: when you assign `attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)` use the denomination such as px EG : `attr("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + 'px')` You're setting it in css as : `width:100` for example, which doesnt mean anything.

Comment: This seems to fix the issue! Thanks very much!